# Dual Pivot QuickSort

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

So i am working on a problem which implements QuickSort with three partitions, choosing the left-most and right-most element of the array as pivots. My function basically does the lomoto partition from the left and right side of the array. The algorithm basically sorts the array for 95% of cases, however there are a couple for which it doesn't work. Anyone know why?

```
public static int[] partition2Pivots(int[] arr, int p, int r) {

    if(arr[p]>arr[r]) {
        int temp = arr[p];
        arr[p] = arr[r];
        arr[r] = temp;
    }

    int pivotLow = arr[p];
    int pivotHigh = arr[r];

    int low = p;
    int high = r;

    for(int j=p; j<=r; j++) {
        if(arr[j]>pivotHigh) {
            high--;
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[high];
            arr[high] = temp;
        }
        if(arr[j]<pivotLow) {
            low++;
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[low];
            arr[low] = temp;
        }
    }
    int temp1 = arr[p];
    arr[p] = arr[low];
    arr[low] = temp1;
    int temp2 = arr[r];
    arr[r] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp2;

    int pivots[] = {low, high};
    return pivots;
}
public static void quickSort2Pivots(int[] arr, int p, int r) {
    if(p<r) {
        int[] pivots = partition2Pivots(arr, p, r);
        quickSort2Pivots(arr, p, pivots[0]);
        quickSort2Pivots(arr, pivots[0]+1, pivots[1]-1);
        quickSort2Pivots(arr, pivots[1], r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible point of failure is in using the same loop for both pivots. Or it could be that the final swapping of p with low and r with high is redundant, because the loop already runs from p to r, both inclusive.

But first, give an example of a failed case, as minimal as you can make it.

Also, you can save much code, along with potential errors, if you encapsulate the code for swapping two array elements in a function swap(arr, i, j).